# JavaFX - How to make custom component resizable in SceneBuilder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, custom-component, resizable

I implemented a custom component (ToggleSwitch) like in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maX5ymmQixM
I created a .jar via Maven and added the .jar to SceneBuilder

The component works but it is not resizable at all and also not resizable in SceneBuilder.
[image]

[image]

**What is necessary for it to be resizeable**?

**What I tried**

I have learnt that extending from Region (not from Parent like in the video) is necessary for SceneBuilder to show the Size-Settings under the Layout-Tab in SceneBuilder
[image]

Here is the code

```
import javafx.animation.FillTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ToggleSwitch extends Region {

    private   double PREFERRED_WIDTH = 100;
    private   double PREFERRED_HEIGHT = 50;

    private final BooleanProperty switchedOn = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private final TranslateTransition translateAnimation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.25));
    private final FillTransition fillAnimation = new FillTransition(Duration.seconds(0.25));
    private final ParallelTransition animation = new ParallelTransition(translateAnimation,fillAnimation);

    private double width;
    private double height;
    private Rectangle background;
    private Circle trigger;


    public ToggleSwitch(){

        width = PREFERRED_WIDTH;
        height = PREFERRED_HEIGHT;
        background = new Rectangle(width,height);
        background.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        background.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        background.setArcWidth(50);
        background.setArcHeight(50);


        trigger = new Circle(height/2);
        trigger.setCenterX(height/2);
        trigger.setCenterY(height/2);
        trigger.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        trigger.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

        translateAnimation.setNode(trigger);
        fillAnimation.setShape(background);

        getChildren().addAll(background,trigger);

        switchedOn.addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            boolean isOn = newState;
            translateAnimation.setToX(isOn ? 100-50 : 0);
            fillAnimation.setFromValue(isOn ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHTGREEN);
            fillAnimation.setToValue(isOn ? Color.LIGHTGREEN : Color.WHITE);
            animation.play();
        });

        setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            switchedOn.set(!switchedOn.get());
        });

        widthProperty().addListener(o->resize());
        heightProperty().addListener(o->resize());

    }
    

    private void resize () {
        width = getWidth() - getInsets().getLeft() - getInsets().getRight();
        height = getHeight();
    }

    public BooleanProperty switchedOnProperty() {
        return switchedOn;
    }
    
}
```

How can I implement it to be resizable so I can use SceneBuilder ?

Comment: Don't add listeners to the `widthProperty` and `heightProperty`. (There doesn't seem to be any purpose to your listeners anyway. All you do is update two private variables which are never used after the object has been constructed.) Instead, override, at a minimum, `layoutChildren()`, get the width and height, and update the size and position of the child nodes accordingly.

Comment: and read the api doc of Region, it describes exactly how to override its sizing requirements.

Comment: @kleopatra 
Yes, indeed. Did not think about it :)

Comment: Do you have any helpfull tutorials on writing custom components for javaFX ?

Comment: Study the [JavaFX controls source](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls).  Start with [`Button`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/Button.java) and [ButtonSkin](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/ButtonSkin.java) and classes in their hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@James_D Thanks that worked pretty good.

Overriding the layoutChildren method worked :)

[image]

[image]

```
public class ToggleSwitch extends Region {

private   double PREFERRED_WIDTH = 100;
private   double PREFERRED_HEIGHT = 50;

private final BooleanProperty switchedOn = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
private final TranslateTransition translateAnimation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.25));
private final FillTransition fillAnimation = new FillTransition(Duration.seconds(0.25));
private final ParallelTransition animation = new ParallelTransition(translateAnimation,fillAnimation);

private double width;
private double height;
private Rectangle background;
private Circle trigger;


public ToggleSwitch(){

    width = PREFERRED_WIDTH;
    height = PREFERRED_HEIGHT;
    background = new Rectangle(width,height);
    background.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    background.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    background.setArcWidth(50);
    background.setArcHeight(50);


    trigger = new Circle(height/2);
    trigger.setCenterX(height/2);
    trigger.setCenterY(height/2);
    trigger.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    trigger.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

    translateAnimation.setNode(trigger);
    fillAnimation.setShape(background);

    getChildren().addAll(background,trigger);

    switchedOn.addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
        boolean isOn = newState;
        translateAnimation.setToX(isOn ? getWidth()-trigger.getRadius()*2 : 0);
        fillAnimation.setFromValue(isOn ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHTGREEN);
        fillAnimation.setToValue(isOn ? Color.LIGHTGREEN : Color.WHITE);
        animation.play();
    });

    setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        switchedOn.set(!switchedOn.get());
    });

}


@Override
protected void layoutChildren(){
    double width = getWidth();
    double height= getHeight();
    background.setWidth(width);
    background.setHeight(height);
    background.setArcWidth(height);
    background.setArcHeight(height);

    trigger.setRadius(height/2);
    trigger.setCenterX(height/2);
    trigger.setCenterY(height/2);
}

public BooleanProperty switchedOnProperty() {
    return switchedOn;
}
```

}

> To implement a more custom layout, a Region subclass must override
> computePrefWidth, computePrefHeight, and layoutChildren. Note that
> layoutChildren is called automatically by the scene graph while
> executing a top-down layout pass and it should not be invoked directly
> by the region subclass.

[Region API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html)

Comment: Note on naming conventions: Using `SNAKE_CASE` is typically reserved for `static final` fields. Either make those fields static and final (which would make sense in your context), or change the naming pattern to `camelCase`.